# How To Show The App Data On The Store By Using The CLI Node App?

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-storefront-api

I am creating custom App using The CLI Node App. I want to show App data at store. I am not found any exact solution for that.

i am building a custom shopify App using The CLI Node. if user uploads any kind of data in our App, i want that data to show on Shopify Store.

Comment: where exactly is your issue? What have you done and then what happens?

Comment: I am creating a custom app where users can upload videos, and they will be displayed in the store

Comment: You've again told what you **need to do**, but what is the **problem** or **question** you have?